# Can you explain this code for me in layman's terms?

Tags: c#, if-statement, statements

I'm doing a project where I need the code to be able to determine if input is odd or not.
(I also need to be able to determine if it is even

Can you explain what this means? Mainly the first part.

```
if((x & 1) == 0)
    printf("EVEN!\n");
else
    printf("ODD!\n");
```

Answer (score 8):

It's a bitwise operation. The AND operation masks every bit and leave the last one. If the last bit is off (you're checking against zero), means it's even otherwise means it's odd.

An example:

125 in binary form is 01111101

so

```
01111101 AND
00000001 =
------------
00000001
```

so 125 is ODD :)

An alternative way to check even or odd is to use the module of division:

```
if (x % 2 == 0) printf("EVEN");
else printf("ODD");
```

As noted by a user in a comment below, this second solution is slower (in terms of μS)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the other answer it is a [bitwise operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx), but the test is actually if the last bit is set it is ODD, hence the `==0`.  So if the last bit is NOT set it is EVEN.

EDIT: Just saw that answer was deleted, oh well.

Comment: fixed in the same moment you're were probably writing :) SO is becaming really competitive and I love it ;)

Comment: No problem even if you did :) And by the way it's nice to meet kind people as you're

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do it would be to:

```
if( x % 2 == 0 )
{
  printf("EVEN!\n");
}
else
{
   printf("ODD!\n");
}
```

The %, or modulus operator, returns the remainder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Comment: Likely not an issue with modern compilers and processors, but modulus is much more expensive operation that bit operations.